# Modify timeout in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, get, timeout

I have a simple question regarding timers in angularjs. I have 2 panes on a page. (left and right) A click on an entry on the left side loads stuff on the right side via a GET request every 10 seconds (Here is where I use a timer). Now a click on another entry on the left side loads some other stuff on the right (every 10 seconds via GET). Now my problem is that the old timer continues to run and sends GET requests every 10 sec. What would be a good way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$timeout.cancel()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) and pass it a reference to your timeouts promise.

```
  function someDelayedFunc(){
      //...
  }

  $scope.timeoutPromise = $timeout(someDelayedFunc, 10000);

  function cancelExistingTimout(){
      $timeout.cancel($scope.timeoutPromise );
  }
```